# filter_horizontal equivalent for a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, admin

I'd like to use the filter_horizontal widget for a ForeignKey. But it doesn't work, which is normal because this widget is for ManyToMany fields. But i'd really like kind of an auto-completion little widget for my ForeignKey. I tested raw_id_fields and the result is pretty good, through I don't like the fact that it opens in a new window.

If you have any idea, besides using a snippet or other stuff like this...